# Closing Votes count bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

So here I am, minding my own business and checking out the [Vote to Close statistics](https://superuser.com/review-beta/close/stats), when I notice a weird number... 25. I voted only 24 times in this UTC day. Weird bug? Or am I just that super awesome that I'm number 1 today?

[image]

Comment: *Reviews* have other possible outcomes than *vote to close*. To be honest, 96% closing sounds like a lot...

Comment: @DanielBeck I read the questions and decide from there. So if I edit the question to improve its quality and make it non-VTC'd, it counts as a review then?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise there would be an insane reward for closing and none for deciding to leave it open. Only *Not sure* doesn't count.

Comment: That's good to know then. Want to make that an answer and I'll mark this?

Comment: I'm fairly sure some people get to 96% closing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot you show counts the number of *reviews* The number of *total close votes for a given day* and the *number of reviews* can be different because:

1. not all close votes count as reviews: if you VTC when viewing a question outside the review queue
2. reviews are also counted when you select *Do Not Close* or *Edit*, not just for *Close*