# Bug or change for close votes?

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

We are limited to 20 close votes a day (I guess depending on points).

Normally, when we reach that threshold, a message appears on screen alerting we've done all the voting we're allowed. At this point, I think we can't even see any more posts.

Today, that is not occurring. I can still see the posts, I am giving a choice to vote and after considering why to close it, I am then alerted I've reached the limit. I found that a little annoying, why show me the post if I can't interact with it (although I won't lose any sleep over it! :)  )

Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: Reference post: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5554/closing-votes-count-bug

Comment: @CanadianLuke, so, we think they are making a few updates here?

Comment: Nah, just saying that post kinda asks about the votes, but gives different behaviour then what you're posting. I couldn't get into the queue once my 24 (at the time) close votes were used, but I did 25 actions because one of the actions was an edit, not a close

Comment: Probably a long-standing bug, but I can't be sure. You normally run out of reviews (limit: 20/day) before you run out of close votes (limit: 24/day), but today you hit the latter first.